# How to remove all entries from redux-persist

Tags: javascript, redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I am using `redux-persist` to restore my state after page refresh.

However I would like to remove all storage when logging out.

I have `redux-persist` set to `localstorage`. Which on logout I use `localStorage.clear();` to make sure it can't reload from there.

However this doesn't remove all of the stage. I would like to have nothing in the redux store and nothing when I reload the page.